# Marginal of tree (root)

Tags: graphical-model, marginal-distribution

Graphical model: $(A) \rightarrow \{C : C \in ch(A)\}$ where $ch(A)$ is the set of children to A. So basically a tree rooted in A with edges pointing away from A.
I have categorical distributions of nodes given their parents' values, that is I have the values for $P(C|A)$ but not $P(A|C)$.

Given some evidence, i want the marginal probability of A.

$P(A|e) = \sum_{C \in ch(A)} P(A|e, C)P(C|e)$

Rewrite first factor by Bayes:

$= \sum_{C \in ch(A)} \frac{P(C|A, e)P(A|e)}{P(C|e)}P(C|e)$

$= P(A|e) \sum_{C \in ch(A)} P(C|A, e)$

If the problem is not obvious, the summation must be one since I have $P(A|e)$ on both sides? What am I doing wrong? How to continue?